# How to build the Mathematics for outage probability.

Tags: probability-distributions, density-function

I am reading a paper that calculates outage probability. I had reached upto following:
Step 1: The outage probability is defined as $P_o = Pr\left(\gamma \geq \gamma_{th}\right)$-----(1), where $\gamma$ is SNR and $\gamma_{th}$ is SNR threshold. Then i have the expression of SNR that i had substituted into definition of SNR which is given in (1). Thus the step 2 is obtained as follows.

Step 2: $P_o = Pr\left(\frac{P_t|h|^2}{\alpha|f|^{2}|g|^{2}P_{t}+\sigma^2}\geq\gamma_{th}\right)$-----(2), where $h,f,g $ are rayleigh random variable, $\sigma^2$ is variance of additive white gaussian noise (AWGN) and $P_t$ is transmit power. After some simple manupulation, i reached upto the step 3.

Step3: $P_o = Pr\left(|h|^{2}\geq\alpha|f|^{2}|g|^{2}\gamma_{th}+\frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}\right)$------(3). After step 3, the step 4 is given as

Step4: $P_o = \int_0^{\infty}\int_{\frac{\gamma_{th}(\alpha P_tx+\sigma^2)}{P_t}}^{\infty}f_{|h|^{2}}(y)f_{|f|^2|g|^2}(x)dydx$------(4)
I am not getting how Eq. (4) is obtained. Any help please.
Note: I apologize for the very long question that I had asked. However I had written so that every one understood my query. And I just want how Eq. (4) is obtained from Eq. (3)

Comment: Can you give me the link to your paper so that I could explain the problem to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that what’s going on is as follows:

First (and check the paper for notation): I think $f_{|h|^2}(y)$ designates the probability density function for a Rayleigh distribution of scale parameter $|h|$.

So the inner integral with respect to $dx$ is accumulating the portion of $P_0$ for a given value of $h$. The lower bound of this integral is the smallest valid value of $h$.

And then the outer integral with respect to $dy$ is accumulating over all values of $h$.

In more detail:
$$\begin{align*}
  P_0 &= Pr\!\left(
    |h|^2 \geq \alpha|f|^2|g|^2\gamma_{th} + \frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}
  \right)
\\&=
  \lim_{\delta y \to 0}
  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}
    Pr\!\left(
      |h|^2 \geq 
      \alpha|f|^2|g|^2\gamma_{th} + \frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}
      \,\Bigg{|}\,
      h = y_k
    \right)
    Pr\Bigl(h \in [y_k,y_{k+1})\Bigr)
    &\text{where $y_k = k\delta y$}
\end{align*}$$
by the law of total probability. Intuitively, we tile the positive number line into intervals of width $\delta y$.  Those are the possible values for $h$.  Now $Pr\Bigl(h \in [y_k,y_{k+1})\Bigr) \approx f_{|h|^2}(y) \delta y$ and the approximation becomes perfect as $\delta y \to 0$ so the sum becomes an integral
$$
P_0 = \int_{0}^{\infty}
      Pr\!\left(
      |h|^2 \geq 
      \alpha|f|^2|g|^2\gamma_{th} + \frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}
      \,\Bigg{|}\,
      h = y
    \right)
   f_{|h|^2}(y) \, dy
$$

I *think* that something similar is going on with the inner integral with respect to $x$, so that
$$\begin{align*}
  Pr\!\left(
      |h|^2 \geq 
      \alpha|f|^2|g|^2\gamma_{th} + \frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}
      \,\Bigg{|}\,
      h = y
    \right)
  &=
  \lim_{\delta x \to 0}
  \sum_{\ell=0}^{\infty}
    Pr\!\left(
      |h|^2 \geq 
      \alpha|f|^2|g|^2\gamma_{th} + \frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}
      \,\Bigg{|}\,
      h = y, |f||g| = x_{\ell}
    \right)
    Pr\Bigl( |f||g| \in [x_{\ell}, x_{\ell+1}) \Bigr)
    & \text{where $x_{\ell} = \ell \delta x$}
\\&=
  \int_{\alpha x \gamma_{th} + \frac{\sigma^2\gamma_{th}}{P_t}}^{\infty}
     f_{|f|^2|g|^2}(x) \, dx
\end{align*}$$

Hence
$$\begin{align*}
  P_0 &= \int_{0}^{\infty}
      \left(
        \int_{\frac{\gamma_{th}(\alpha P_t x + \sigma^2)}{P_t}}^{\infty}
          f_{|f|^2|g|^2}(x) \, dx
      \right)
   f_{|h|^2}(y) \, dy
\\&=
  \int_{0}^{\infty}
  \int_{\frac{\gamma_{th}(\alpha P_t x + \sigma^2)}{P_t}}^{\infty}
    f_{|h|^2}(y)
    f_{|f|^2|g|^2}(x) 
    \, dy dx
\end{align*}$$
where the last step is from rearranging the order of the integration and bringing the factor $f_{|h|^2}(y)$ inside the inner integral.

Comment: Ok.....although thats not the complete answer to my query. But your answer has taken my understanding to the next level.

Comment: I had another query in Eq.(4) that why there is multiplication between PDF of $|h|^2$ and PDF of $|f|^{2}|g|^{2}$

Comment: I *think* the PDF of $|h|^2$ is weighting the integral with respect to $dx$, and in principle could be moved outside that integral.

Comment: Can you please explain it by small example....